# Getting a XML file as response in C# from Azure

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, azure, reporting-services

We have a RDL and XML file on Azure. I have a fullURI to a path with loginId and password (of Azure) which can download a xml file directly.

**In a browser, this link (fullURI) will**
1. Open Azure Login Page.
2. On entering the credentials it opens up a dialog that will ask you - Do you want to Open / Save / Cancel the xml file? 
3. If we select Open then it will open the XML file in the browser.

**In WP7 application with C# code we are trying to access the xml from above. The code snippet is as given below.**

```
protected class GetContext
{
    public HttpWebRequest Request;
}
```

***Request***

```
HttpWebRequest xmlReportRequest;

… …. 
// baseuri is a HTTPS link to azure reporting server.
URI fullUri = new Uri(baseuri + "&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=XML"); 
xmlReportRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(fullUri.Uri);
xmlReportRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);

// start the asynchronous request
xmlReportRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(HandleResponse),    new GetContext {   Request = request });

);
```

***Response***

```
private void HandleResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    var context = (GetFContext)result.AsyncState;
    WebResponse response = context.Request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);

    //get the stream containing the response from the async call
    Stream streamResult;
    streamResult  =  response.GetResponseStream();

    // load the XML
    _xmlDocument = XElement.Load(streamResult); // EXCEPTION AT THIS LINE NOTSUPPORTEDEXCEPTION

   ….   …         …

}
```

Here, the output of GetResponseStream is not a XML file. When the stream is stored into a string we see that it is the Azure login page as a HTML.

***RESPONSE FROM GETRESPONSESTREAM*** which I feel is just a HTML azure login page (with the information that we sent). Below is the response, here i have replaced some confidential information with URL_TO_THE_XML_FILE_IN_REPORTING_SERVER (it is basically target uri), SOME_ENCRYPTED_VALUE.

```
\r\n<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" >\r\n\r\n\r\n<html lang=\"en-US\">\r\n   <head id=\"Head1\"><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1\" /><link rel=\"Stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"Public/Logon.css\" /><title>\r\n\tWindows Azure SQL Reporting\r\n</title></head>\r\n   <body >\r\n      <form name=\"Logon\" method=\"post\" action=\"logon.aspx?ReturnUrl=URL_TO_THE_XML_FILE_IN_REPORTING_SERVER\" id=\"Logon\">\r\n<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"__VIEWSTATE\" id=\"__VIEWSTATE\" value=\"/SOME_ENCRYPTED_VALUE\" />\r\n\r\n<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"__EVENTVALIDATION\" id=\"__EVENTVALIDATION\" value=\"/SOME_ENCRYPTED_VALUE\" />\r\n\r\n        <h1 id=\"Title\"><span id=\"LblTitleContent\">Windows Azure</span></h1>\r\n        <hr />\r\n        <div class=\"ClsIntro\">\r\n            <span id=\"LblIntro\"></span>\r\n        </div>\r\n        <div class=\"ClsInput\">\r\n            <div>\r\n                <label for=\"TxtUser\" id=\"LblUser\">User name</label>\r\n            </div>\r\n            <div>\r\n                <input name=\"TxtUser\" type=\"text\" id=\"TxtUser\" tabindex=\"1\" />\r\n            </div>\r\n        </div>\r\n        <div class=\"ClsInput\">\r\n            <div>\r\n                <label for=\"TxtPwd\" id=\"LblPwd\">Password</label>\r\n            </div>\r\n            <div>\r\n                <input name=\"TxtPwd\" type=\"password\" id=\"TxtPwd\" tabindex=\"2\" />\r\n            </div>\r\n        </div>\r\n        <div class=\"ClsSignIn\">\r\n            <input type=\"submit\" name=\"BtnLogon\" value=\"Sign in\" id=\"BtnLogon\" tabindex=\"4\" /><input type=\"image\" name=\"BtnLogonArrow\" id=\"BtnLogonArrow\" tabindex=\"5\" src=\"Public/WhiteRightArrow.png\" alt=\"Sign in\" align=\"baseline\" border=\"0\" />\r\n        </div>\r\n        <div class=\"ClsErrMsg\">\r\n            <span id=\"lblMessage\"></span>\r\n        </div>\r\n        <hr />\r\n      </form>\r\n   </body>\r\n</html>
```

***Questions***

1. Even though network credentials are passed why are we getting a HTML response with the login page?
2. What might cause the exception in  in this line? -  _xmlDocument = XElement.Load(streamResult)
3. Are we missing anything in the way we are accessing the Azure hosted XML from C# code?
4. Should we be rather looking at the server side  for correcting the URL to the direct XML file based on what you can understand from the first four lines of our problem description?

Thanks in Advance,

Trilok Rangan.

Comment: How are you creating the XML file? The NotSupportedException often indicates that something is wrong with your XML file.

Comment: we are getting a HTML file as response and not a XML file Hence the NotSupportedException I believe.

Comment: How are you returning the XML file? Please show some server side code

Comment: @SandrinoDiMattia - There is no our own code running at server side because it is just running on Reporting Service. I am connecting to a reporting service.

Comment: @Erno - Right. HTML is not the expected XML. I have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: What did you specify as the MIME type of the response?

Comment: Could you update the question and add an example of what you're getting back from Reporting Services?

Comment: @Erno - We have not specified any MIME type. Should we be doing it? If so, could you post an example code?

Answer (score 1):

Getting html back might be caused by running into a generic error handling page on the server when encountering an exception.

So make sure you return xml in all cases, even in case of an exception.

The exception can be caused by security issues or any other error on the server.

Make sure the content type that is set by the server is correct.

If the file is stored in blob-storage: [mark the file's mime type in the blob storage explorer](http://blogs.solidq.com/pdoshi/post.aspx?id=4&title=hosting%20a%20static%20website%20in%20azure%20blobs%20-%20setting%20content%20type%20%5B%20mime%20type%20%5D%20of%20the%20blob%20content)

If the file is static content: [add the mime type in the web.config using the mimeMap element](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/03/25/how-to-add-mime-types-with-iis7-web-config.aspx):

```
<configuration>

    <system.webServer>

        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".m4v" mimeType="video/m4v" />
        </staticContent>

    </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```